# Squeeze multiple comments in a single word in dataframe

Tags: python

I have the dataframe like below.

dataframe1 =

```
  Product  comment1                   comment2                     comment3
0   P10    not fresh                  0                            short life time
1   P11    Quality is good            comparatively cheap          nice product
2   P12    got banned 1 year ago      was not that good            demand is poor
3   P13    just got expired           0                            no demand at all
4   P14    nice product               good customer satisfaction   0
5   P15    very bad                   0                            affects health of user
6   P16    limited stock              high demand                  0
7   P17    0                          0                            high customer satisfaction
8   P18    very expensive             bad quality                  0
9   P19    shinny                     0                            cheap
10  P20    0                          always in stock              most searched product
```

I want to squeeze all the comments for a particular product into a single 'good' or 'bad'.
like if 'not fresh' is there in any comment, it is 'bad'. Similarly 'short life', 'banned', 'not good', 'expired', 'no demand', 'bad', 'very expensive'  etc. defines 'bad'.
Similarly, 'high satisfaction', 'nice', 'cheap', 'shinny'  etc. all defines 'good'.

The final result that I want looks like below.

```
Product   squeezed_comment
P10          bad
P11          good
P12          bad
P13          bad
P14          good
P15          bad
P16          bad
P17          good
P18          bad
P19          good
P20          good
```

how to do this?
thanks in advance.

Comment: can you do `dataframe1.to_dict()` and share so we can copy past and use it.

Comment: What should be the answer when there is both bad word and good word present for some product. Can this be the case?

Comment: And consider 'not cheap', 'not very expensive' and so on.